# How to compute multidimensional omega with R

Tags: r, reliability, likert

I need to perform a computation of reliability of a 5-point Likert scale having 6 items. From a factor analysis I found that my scale is a multidimensional scale (3 factors), so I cannot use Cronbach's alpha to compute reliability. I have seen in several papers that it is possible to use the multidimensional extension of the McDonald's omega. Does the `omega` function in the **psych** package allow to do this?

Also, is there  an R function to compute the Stratified alpha?

Comment: It would help if you answered the questions I asked for your preceding question... (and please register your account so that you could vote and accept @Jeromy's earlier answer.)

Comment: it seems you are asking 2 not related questions, please ask separately. Also if you leave unanswered clarifications asked in your previous questions, people will hesitate in answering your new questions.

Answer (score 1):

First yes it does, see http://www.personality-project.org/r/psych/help/omega.html and second  there is a package `sirt` http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sirt/docs/stratified.cronbach.alpha that you can use for stratified alpha.